# Controlling Subform Records and Tab Control Pages?

Tags: ms-access, combobox, duplicates, visibility, beforeupdate

I have a form for "Contacts".  this has a tab control with sub forms.  One of the pages has a continuous sub form for requirements.  9 of these 12 requirement types have a corresponding tab page and subform.  I use a public function to check the visibility of the page, so that I'm making sure the only pages visible, are ones that have been set to have a requirement.

The other things I need to be able to control are as follows:

1. If someone deletes a requirement, I have to check that requirements contact - requirement detail table for any detail records.  A user can add a contact requirement.  That will show that tab page and sub form, but the user may never fill in any details for that requirement.  So the code looks for sub records in that requirement. If there are any, the user is warned and asked to confirm they want to delete the detail records.  If yes, those are deleted, and then the contact requirement record itself is deleted.  If there are no detail records, then that contact requirement record is just deleted.
2. if someone goes to add a new requirement, before that new record is added, I need to check that this contact record, doesn't aready have a contact requirement record for that same requirement type.  If so, tell them they can't do that, and back it out.

so here is the code for checking the visibility of the pages, based on the requirement types in the contact requirement table, for the current contact.  For clarity, I added columns to the tblReqType table.  It has ID and txtRequirementType.  It also has txtRequirementPage and txtRequirementTable, which have the names of the pages and source tables, if the requirement type has corresponding page and tables to be identified.

```
Public Function ShowReqs(MCID As Integer)
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim ReqPages As String
    Dim ShowReqPages As DAO.Recordset
    Dim IsReq As Integer
    Dim showpg As Variant
    Dim reqrec As Integer
    Dim ctl As Control

    If Forms!frmMContacts.Detail.Visible = True Then
        Forms!frmMContacts.frmMContacts_SubRequirements.Form.Dirty = False

        Set db = CurrentDb

        ReqPages = "SELECT tblReqType.ID, tblReqType.txtRequirementPage, tblReqType.txtRequirementTable " & _
                        "FROM tblReqType " & _
                        "WHERE tblReqType.txtRequirementPage is not null;"

        Set ShowReqPages = db.OpenRecordset(ReqPages, dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)

        Forms!frmMContacts.Painting = False

        Do While Not ShowReqPages.EOF
            IsReq = DCount("*", "tblMContactRequirements", "FKMC = " & Nz(Forms!frmMContacts.ID, 0) & " and FKRequirementType = " & ShowReqPages.Fields("ID"))
            If IsReq = 0 Then
                showpg = False
            Else
                showpg = True
            End If
            Forms!frmMContacts.tbMContactsubs.Pages(ShowReqPages.Fields("txtRequirementPage")).Visible = showpg
            For Each ctl In Forms!frmMContacts.tbMContactsubs.Pages(ShowReqPages.Fields("txtRequirementPage")).Controls
                With ctl
                    Select Case .ControlType
                    Case acSubform
                        ctl.Form.Requery
                    End Select
                End With
            Next ctl

        ShowReqPages.MoveNext
        Loop

        Forms!frmMContacts.Painting = True
        Forms!frmMContacts.Repaint
        Set db = Nothing
        Set ShowReqPages = Nothing
    End If
End Function
```

This seems to work, but it gets in the way when I'm trying to catch an addition of a duplicate requirement type, for the same contact id.  I need to catch that, before it gets passed ot the table, which is in SQL.  This is because I put an index on the tblMContactRequirements table for the FKMC (contact id) and the FKRequirementType columns, to have those 2 together to be unique.  It throws a nasty odbc message about the index, and I want to get ahead of that, check for potential duplication, and back it out if it would make a dup/trip the index error.

In the sub requirements form, I was putting the following in the Before_Update, and then the Before_Insert.  Either way, I get weird issues.  It's hard to point them out, because I can't tell what is causing what to happen.  I troubleshoot 1 thing, and then another issues comes up.

This is the code, meant to catch dupes:

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeInsert(Cancel As Integer)
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim reqrec As Integer
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
Set rst = Me.RecordsetClone
rst.FindFirst "[FKRequirementType] = " & Me.FKRequirementType & " AND [FKMC] = " & Me.Parent!ID
If Not rst.NoMatch Then
    MsgBox "This requirement has already been added! ", vbOKOnly, "Requirements Shouldn't be Added Twice."
    Me.Undo
    BeforeResult = 1
Else
    BeforeResult = 0
End If
rst.Close
Me.Dirty = False
```

I tried putting this in the requirement type combo control's on change:

```
Private Sub FKRequirementType_Change()
Form_BeforeInsert (0)
If BeforeResult = 1 Then
Exit Sub
Else
    Form_AfterUpdate
End If
End Sub
```

I tried putting this in the after update of the form:

```
Private Sub Form_AfterUpdate()
Dim FKMC As Integer
FKMC = Nz(Me.Parent!ID, 0)
Call ShowReqs(FKMC)
End Sub
```

I don't know if I'm over-coding this, putting things in the wrong places, or what.

If anyone can help me figure this out, I would so appreciate another set of eyes!

Comment: Within `Form_BeforeInsert()` rather than calling Me.Undo, instead set `Cancel = True` and let the form's built-in behavior work as designed.  Instead of calling Form_BeforeInsert() directly from other procedures, create a new sub procedure with common code and call that instead.  Then you can have better control over precisely how different conditions are handled.  This is a good pattern to help avoid trying to code event handlers for all possible scenarios.  Same goes for other event handlers like Form_AfterUpdate().  This might reduce some "weird behavior".

Comment: What does "gets in the way" mean? From the description it seems perfectly reasonable to be able to check for duplicates before performing other actions, but it's not clear why the one function prevents the code from checking for other conditions.  If you're not able to describe the problem precisely beyond "weird", you may need to disable code and work on one aspect at a time. Place Debug.Print calls to trace the order of execution, logging form and control properties, etc.

Comment: With all due respect, I've provided lots of code and explanation. I ended up figuring it out.  I will post the answer shortly.

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution!  But with the same due respect, providing lots of code with lists of multiple requirements along with vague problem descriptions go beyond the expected type of question on Stack Overflow.  There are other forums where that is the norm, but SO is purposefully different.  See #1 about _debugging help_ on [this help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for hints about writing more concise, focused questions.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer to this.  This is the change event for the combo now:

```
Private Sub FKRequirementType_Change()
Dim i As Integer
    If Nz(Me.FKRequirementType) <> 0 Then
        i = DCount("*", "tblMContactRequirements", "FKMC=" & Me.Parent!ID & " And FKRequirementType=" & Me.FKRequirementType.Value)
        If (i > 0) Then
            MsgBox "This contact already has a " & Me.FKRequirementType.Column(1) & " requirement.", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, "No Duplicates!"
            Me.Undo
        Else
            Call ShowReqs(FKMC)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Position, position, position.  It really matters where you call the check on the procedure that is running.

Thanks for all the responses and help!

Comment: I'm glad this works for you and it may prove sufficient. But similar to what I mentioned before, using FKRequirementType_BeforeUpdate event and setting Cancel = True might be more robust. The event model in Access is quirky to say the least, and sometimes there are strange behaviors that occur with the Change events depending on if a user selects with a mouse vs. using the keyboard vs. cut and paste, etc. - some random combination might still allow a duplicate entry. Adding similar code in the form Before_Update and Before_Insert with Cancel = True is still good insurance against bad data.

Comment: Thanks. I'm definitely with you.  My other concern is that access also sucks at catching ODBC errors.  I will maybe revisit this, after I get my huge to do list under control.  For now, it is working. I definitely look forward to improving how it's written, down the road.